# htaccess redirect query string, but encoded ? to &

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect

https://www.aaa.com/query?v=abc123_ABC

to:
https://bbb.com/?url=https://www.aaa.com/query?v=abc123_ABC

I use this in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://bbb.com/?url=https://www.aaa.com/$1  [L,B,NE,NC,QSA,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

But the output is:
https://bbb.com/?url=https://www.aaa.com/query&v=abc123_ABC

The ? was converted into &, what's wrong with the code?
Thanks.

====
You can test it here:
https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Just want to double check here, you want the whole url to passed as query string to new domain url? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  Yes.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The problem is the 1st ?, if there is no such ?, it will works fine.

Comment: I have the rules ready for this one but problem is `https://bbb.com/?` if I change `/?` to `/` then only it works, its not taking multiple `?` in uri, which I believe is not allowed, let me know if you really need 2 times `?` here?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  Yes, I need.

Comment: A valid URL can have only one `?`. Next `?` should be encode as `%3F`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following rule should work.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /query\?v=.+\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://bbb.com/?url=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}  [L,R]
```

Comment: @thodison Your welcome. The updated version should work as intended.

Answer (score 3):

As per OP's request and shown samples could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(/query)\?(v=abc123_ABC)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://bbb.com/?url=https://%{HTTP_HOST}%1?%2 [NE,L]
```

Comment: Not working. Tested here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: @thodison, when I tested with localhost with redirects it to `Location: http://localhost:80/?url=https://localhost/query?v=abc123_ABC` successfully as per your shown samples.

Comment: @thodison, I am not sure on that site but with `curl` command on my local machine it worked fine for me.

Comment: Thank you, I will tested it later.

Comment: @RavinderSingh `{THE_REQUEST}` variable doesn't match against `URL scheme` and `Host` header so `http[s]?://www\.aaa\.com/` must be romved from the condition pattern. Anyway nice try.  ed .

Comment: @AmitVerma, Thank you for letting me know and encouragement, when I check by curl `Location: http://localhost:80/?url=https://localhost/query?v=abc123_ABC` that's why I posted, I removed 2nd solution now, please do let me know if this looks good, cheers.